# The cause of higher harmonics amplitude drop in an air column?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, acoustics, oscillators, harmonics

In the case of the real life string, I believe I understand the cause of the amplitude drop as we go into higher harmonics: the bendability of the string is not infinite and as we get lower wavelengths that need to bend for higher frequencies, they behave more like a rigid stick than the idealized string. The string is simply unable to achieve the same amplitude.

What is the cause of the drop in amplitude of the higher harmonics in the air column, and why?

Edit:
My intuitive answer would be that, if we for example take a trumpet, that all the small differences in the thickness of the metal and it's geometry is what creates the higher frequencies - but only a small amount of energy gets directed toward this vibration. The amount varies from instrument to instrument, vibration of the lips and the intensity of playing.

My second guess would be this information found on this fascinating
page on brass acoustics (http://newt.phys.unsw.edu.au/jw/brassacoustics.html#harmonics)
which implies that the spectra is significantly created due to non-linearities in the the way we drive the system:
"Remember, however, that the spectrum depends strongly on how loudly you play. The larger the vibration of the lips, the more non-linear the vibration, so the more strong high harmonics present in the sound."

Same page states:
"because the bell effectively radiates high frequencies rather than reflecting them, the resonances become successively weaker at high frequency"
I am not sure why this is so? Is it because of the way the change in the length of the air column diagonally will far greatly affect lower wavelengths, which will disperse into an array of different high frequencies, with offset phases? While the longer wavelengths will see much lesser difference? However the text states that it's due to high frequencies "radiating" rather than reflecting, how come?

The only other reason I can think of is the shear number of air particles needed, as the contrast between the density in the compressions and rarefactions is what constitutes amplitude in soundwaves, as far as I understand it. The lower fq with longer wavelengths simply have more particles at their disposal within the bigger volume of air they encompass so the contrast in this compression-rarefaction gradient can be steeper.

Any ideas or explanations greatly appreciated. :)
Thank you!

Comment: Does this help? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/565593/why-does-higher-frequency-sound-dampen-faster-in-air

Comment: Not at all. The way sound is damped is not necessarily what dictates what the distribution of energy will be among harmonics. Besides, they are talking about high fq dissipating faster when traveling through the medium. The length of, lets say a trumpet is not nearly long enough to explain the difference in amplitudes of harmonics. Damping overall might, but they sure didn't explain why (as it applies to this problem).

Comment: PS I see how the title might be misleading, but it's the drop in amplitude overall/initially that I'm interested in, not the drop over time.